# Correct position of reflexive pronoun and finite verb?

Tags: word-order

The following sentence is from "Spiegel".

Alles begann damit, daß viele Bewohner Hongkongs sich nicht mehr gängeln lassen wollten.

Firstly,
  The rule is, when a noun and a pronoun occur together in a subordinate clause, then the shorter of the two comes first.
Secondly, when two infinitive forms come together in a subordinate clause, the finite verb comes immediately before the first infinitive.
  Thus: ....daß *sich* viele Bewohner nicht mehr *wollten* gängeln lassen.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly, The rule is, when a noun and a pronoun occur together in a subordinate clause, then the shorter of the two comes first*

It's pronouns before nouns. But that's not a rule, only a tendency, and another tendency says subject before objects. Both variants are okay.

*Secondly, when two infinitive forms come together in a subordinate clause, the finite verb comes immediately before the first infinitive.*

That's an alternative to the general rule the finite form comes last. It creates a pretty tight tension and you should not use it unless you want that tension.

Comment: Conclusion: one can say that the original sentence is grammatical, however the word order *daß **sich** viele Bewohner Hongkongs nicht mehr gängeln lassen wollten* would be more common.